# Group By to get min transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Currently I have a list of transactions as below:

```
Front Office ID    Transaction ID    TradeDate    SettlementDate
10000              1234              2015-03-03   2015-03-04
10000              1235              2015-03-03   2015-06-17
10001              1232              2015-03-13   2015-03-18
10001              1231              2015-03-13   2015-06-17
```

What I need to do is find transaction ID's per Front Office ID which has the shortest number of days between trade date and settlement.

I know how to get the date difference, but I'm confused as to how to get this to work in a group by:

```
MIN(DATEDIFF(DD,FX.TradeDate,FX.SettleDate))
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction greatly received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a `GROUP BY` if you want to "find transaction ID's **per Front Office ID** which has the shortest number of days between trade date and settlement"?

```
SELECT TOP 1 t.[Transaction ID] 
FROM dbo.Transactions t
WHERE t.[Front Office ID] = @FrontOfficeID
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DD,  t.TradeDate, t.SettleDate) ASC
```

If you instead want to find it for all transaction ID's you could use a CTE + `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.[Transaction ID],  t.[Front Office ID], t.TradeDate, t.SettleDate
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Front Office ID] 
                                   ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DD,  t.TradeDate, t.SettleDate) ASC)
    FROM dbo.Transactions t
)
SELECT [Transaction ID],  [Front Office ID], TradeDate, SettleDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

If you want to return all transaction ID's which have the shortest timespan between TradeDate and SettleDate(in case of ties), use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: that makes so much more sense.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @chrissyp: note that i've edited my answer to show that you can select all columns with the CTE, not only the `Transaction ID`. What are you using, the `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group it by Front Office ID and then make order by data difference and you will get the min.

Something like this:

```
SELECT id  
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY difference
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and do a `PARTITION BY` on `[Front Office ID]`.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
    SELECT
        [Front Office ID] ,
        [Transaction ID],
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY [Front Office ID] ORDER BY DATEDIFF(DD,FX.TradeDate,FX.SettleDate) ASC) rn
    FROM FX
)
SELECT [Front Office ID] ,[Transaction ID]
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```